# Need javascript validation for one, and only one, numeric in password

Tags: javascript

Need javascript validation for one and only one numeric in password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(/\d/.test(str) && !/\d.*\d/.test(str)) {
    // Exactly one digit
}
```

Comment: Hooray for drive-by-downvoters!

Comment: I would assume you were downvoted by people who disagree with the requirement (such as myself).  (it wasn't me)

Comment: @minitech: I know you're just giving the OP what he wants, but don't encourage him :) (P.S. I'm not one of the downvoters)

Comment: Or by people who disagree with answering 'will-you-do-this-for-me' questions.

Comment: @SLaks: I realize that. I just posted a correct answer that's about as terse as the question ;) But don't take out bad question anger on me, anyone.

Comment: Or by people who think it's silly to complain about a single downvote when you have over 15,000 rep. ;-)

Comment: @mblase75: It has nothing to do with the rep, ever. I just like to know why people think my answer is bad.